# Почему данный код вписывает в файл числа только до 359?

Tags: c#

```
FileStream str = new FileStream(@"D:\e.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(str);
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    stream.Write(i + ",");
    stream.WriteLine();
}
str.Close();
```

Почему данный код вписывает в файл числа только до 359?

Comment: Потому что запись идет через буфер, надо буфер очищать перед закрытием потока.

Comment: @Bulson в C# он автоматически не чистится при закрытии?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
using (FileStream str = new FileStream(@"D:\e.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(str);
    stream.AutoFlush = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        stream.Write(i + ",");
        stream.WriteLine();

    }
    str.Close();
}
```

Comment: Не-а, всё равно нужно сначала закрыть `stream`.